# App upload rejected in google play store reason Hi-res icon

Tags: android, image, android-studio, google-play, google-play-console

While uploading app in google paly store for new update continuously update rejected (Reason Hi-res icon) after I change icon still not accept the update.

[image]

but In play console app status still In Review

[image]

how to fix this problem?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: Seems like Google Play believes your app's icon resembles the icon of another app to the extent that the user may be confused. Try to change your app's icon.

Comment: Can you attach your icon to the question?

Comment: no I forgot that.....

Comment: please share you app icon

Comment: this is my icon                                                                    https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Ficonarchive.com%2Fshow%2Fagriculture-icons-by-aha-soft%2Fcow-head-icon.html&psig=AOvVaw2SyHLIgaF1WVcmNo2bbAAX&ust=1634350332045000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAsQjRxqFwoTCKD98sury_MCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAL

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the image, this image is not allowed for commercial use, you should change it.

[image: screen]

Comment: Thanks for the information....   but reject reason is hi res icon

Comment: The app icon is the hi res icon in the market

Comment: Thank you.  App still in suspend after live I will update.......